# Home share between iPhone and Macbook not working

Tags: home-sharing

My home share between my iPhone and Macbook is not working. My macbook music will show up on my iPhone but it doesn't work the other way around. Someone please help! I've tried basically everything.

Answer (score 1):

Home Sharing does not work in that direction, meaning you can only share music stored on your Mac but not music stored on an iOS device.

---

The only way to view your iPhone music library on a computer is to connect it with iTunes and view it. This can be done in either of two ways:

- Plug the iPhone into your MacBook with a dock connector USB cable. Open iTunes and find the appropriate item in the sidebar under Devices.
- Plug in the iPhone and set up iTunes Wi-Fi Sync: Select the iPhone in iTunes, and under Options you should see something that says "Sync with this iPhone over Wi-Fi." Tick that option and apply settings. Once it's finished, unplug the iPhone (*without* ejecting it first) and you should see it remain in the iTunes sidebar. This will let you access its music wirelessly.

[image: iTunes screenshot]
The above photo says "iPod", but it's the same steps for iPhone.